# Quadratic equation having roots are symmetric/non-symmetric function of another quadrating equation

Tags: polynomials

Bit curious to know why these equations tend to behave like this.

Let $f(x)=x^2+3x+2=0•••(1)$ be a function whose two roots are $\alpha=-1$ and $\beta=-2$.

$\therefore \alpha+\beta=-3$ and $\alpha\beta=2$

Another  equation whose roots are symmetric function of $\alpha$ and $\beta$,which are $\gamma=\alpha+\frac1\beta=-\frac3 2 $ and $\delta=\beta+\frac1\alpha=-3$ is $2x^2+9x+9=0•••(2)$

To obtain second equation we could simply assign $x$( variable of second equation)$=\gamma=\alpha+\frac1\beta=\frac{\alpha\beta+1} \beta=\frac{2+1} \beta=\frac3\beta
=>\beta=\frac3 x$

By putting this value of $\beta$ in the $1^{st}$ equation we ibtain the second equation. Using the value of $\delta$ we will obtain the similar equation.

Upto this I could understand that the function of roots is a link between two equations which is like transformation.

But when the roots aren't symmetric functions then why do we obtain different equations for inserting the functions of the two roots in the first equation? Isn't the function of roots linking both equations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Another equation whose roots are symmetric function of α and β

But $\alpha+ \dfrac{1}{\beta}$ is *not* a symmetric function of $\alpha,\beta$.

What is true, however, is that if the new roots can be written as  $\gamma=h(\alpha,\beta), \delta=h(\beta,\alpha)$ for some function $h$, then $\gamma+\delta$ and $\gamma\delta$ are symmetric functions of $\alpha,\beta$, so it is possible to construct the equation having $\gamma,\delta$ as roots using the symmetric functions of $\alpha,\beta\,$ i.e. without solving the original equation.

In this example, without using OP's partial substitution trick:

- $\displaystyle \gamma+\delta=\alpha+\frac{1}{\alpha}+\beta+\frac{1}{\beta}=\left(\alpha+\beta\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{\alpha\beta}\right)=(-3)\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right)=-\frac{9}{2}$
- $\displaystyle \gamma\delta=\alpha\beta+1+1+\frac{1}{\beta\alpha}=2+\alpha\beta+\frac{1}{\alpha\beta}=2+2+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{9}{2}$

It follows that the quadratic with roots $\gamma,\delta$ is $x^2 + \dfrac{9}{2}x+\dfrac{9}{2}=0 \iff 2x^2+9x+9=0\,$.

---

[ *EDIT* ] $\;$ Following up on comments regarding this part of the original post.

> To obtain second equation we could simply assign $x$( variable of second equation)$=\gamma=\alpha+\frac1\beta=\frac{\alpha\beta+1} \beta=\frac{2+1} \beta=\frac3\beta
> =>\beta=\frac3 x$
>
> By putting this value of $\beta$ in the $1^{st}$ equation we ibtain the second equation. Using the value of $\delta$ we will obtain the similar equation.

- The notation would be less confusing if it used a different variable for the transformation, for example $\color{red}{y} = \gamma = \dots \implies \beta=\frac{3}{y} \implies f\left(\frac{3}{y}\right) = 0 \implies 2y^2+9y+9=0$.
- Just the $\gamma=\frac{3}{\beta}$ condition is not enough to derive the equation. For example, it is also true in this case that $\gamma=\frac{3}{2}\alpha$, but substituting $x=\frac{2}{3}y$ in the original equation does not produce the correct result.

  The implicit assumption here is that not only $\gamma = \frac{3}{\beta}$ but also $\delta=\frac{3}{\alpha}$, and this is what allows the substitution to work.

A more direct (and general) way to state it would be: let $x_1=\alpha,x_2=\beta$ be the roots of $f(x)=0$, and let $y_1=\gamma=g(x_1), y_2=\delta=g(x_2)$ for some function $g$. If $g$ is invertible, then the equation having $y_1,y_2$ as roots is $f\left(g^{-1}(x)\right)=0\,$.

Comment: By symmetric function I meant if we interchange $\alpha$ and $\beta$ from the functions of $\gamma$ and $\delta$ we will obtain the same roots again as well as the same equation.

Comment: I guess I should have mentioned symmetric roots instead of symmetric function..........to be honest I don't know what it is called/named

Comment: @MSKB Right, that is what I meant to clarify by that auxiliary function $h$, in this case $h(a,b)=a+\frac{1}{b}$.

Comment: That means I missed out the part of sum and product of roots which are basically symmetric functions. So because of their symmetry however we consider any root the output must be the same but in the other cases they do not remain symmetric anymore and their application part ways depending on their value that is why we do not obtain same equation for partial substitution of both roots. Is it correct?

Comment: Another thing why do we obtain one specific equation instead of a bunch of equations associated with different SECOND root for partially substituting one root in case of non symmetric functions?

Comment: @MSKB The notation is somewhat confusing in the original post where you mix the variable $x$ and the actual roots. What follows there is $\gamma = \frac{3}{\beta}$, not $\gamma = \frac{3}{x}$. In a similar way you have $\delta = \frac{3}{\alpha}$, so $\gamma,\delta$ are the roots of the equation resulting from the substitution $x \mapsto \frac{3}{x}$. There are *not* two different equations, and there is no ambiguity about it.

Comment: @MSKB I edited the answer and added some more notes at the end.